# with This below Code i am getting error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items' ,

Tags: python, django

```
import json
import simplejson
import urllib2

data = urllib2.urlopen('www.example.com/url/where/i/get/json/data').read()

j = ""
j = simplejson.loads(data)

dump_data=simplejson.dumps(j)

for data in j["facets"]:
    print data.items()
    print "\n----------------\n"
```

Comment: If you had included a real, working URL in your code, then I could reproduce the error and see what is the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says it all.  Clearly `j["facets"]` is an iterable which contains at least some strings instead of containing some other datatype which has an `items` method.  (maybe you expected a dict)?

Try printing `j["facets"]` to see what you're actually getting there.  Then you might be able to figure out why you're getting a string instead of the expected object (`dict`).

Answer (score 1):

Title contains the answer

`j["facets"]` is probably a list of string items